# Which (if any) union filesystems allow you to mount them without an underlying filesystem?

Tags: git, overlayfs, aufs, unionfs

I am considering using a union filesystem, such as aufs, UnionFS or OverlayFS.

I have a 138GB of Android source, to which I want to make minor changes and keep them under version control.

My plan is to mount a unionfs on top of the (now read-only) Android source, and make edits on the unionfs.

In order to commit changes to version control, I will also need to have a view of the unionfs *without* the underlying, read-only, Android source.

Do any of the union filesystems allow a volume to be mounted simultaneously with and without an underlying filesystem?

(If not the strategy could still work, but would require some unmounting and mounting around every commit.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MergerFS](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs) for this. With this you need to mount your disks as you would do normally and use MergerFS to mount one on top of another.

[Excellent podcast episode with the developer of MergerFS](https://extras.show/28)

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation reads: "mergerfs does not support the copy-on-write (CoW) behavior found in aufs and overlayfs. You can not mount a read-only filesystem and write to it.", so I think this is a non-starter.

Comment: That is correct but the next line states "However, mergerfs will ignore read-only drives when creating new files so you can mix read-write and read-only drives.". Which means you can mount your read only Android file system and your Git volume on top of that. Writes only go to the writable Git volume.

Comment: If I edit a file from the read-only drive, will a read-write version of it be automatically created on the read-write drive?  (I will rarely be creating new files, if at all.)

Comment: Since MergerFS does not support copy-on-write, that is not possible. But OverlayFS is a good choice. Docker uses that (at least as default on my Ubuntu machine) to handle all the image layers on top of each other with copy-on-write support.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will take a closer look a OverlayFS.